# MpMoviePlayerController streaming video problem in simulator

Tags: objective-c, ipad

I am working on MPMoviePlayerController, I am playing a video which is in URL @"http://www... xyz...  ITs not playing in simulator.

I am

```
NSString *url = @"hhttp://www... xyz...  ";
MPMoviePlayerController *moviePlayer = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:[NSURL URLWithString:url]];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
NSString *urlStr = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"video.mp4" ofType:nil];
NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:urlStr];
moviePlayer = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:url];
[self.view addSubview:moviePlayer.view];
moviePlayer.view.frame = CGRectMake(50, 50, 200, 200);  
[moviePlayer play];
```